# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.3.33' (using password: YES) on jelastic

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jelastic

I was doing my project on jelastic I have used glassfish server and mySQL when I tried running it I get this error "java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.3.33' (using password: YES)"
the thing is mySQL node info is showing it is connected using the IP should be  "192.168.3.32" can anybody help me plz

2016-08-22T07:04:31.839186Z 55 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.3.33' (using password: YES)

I have granted all the privileges to the root user but still something is wrong

Comment: may be password is wrong

Comment: Please provide output of `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';` and `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'192.168.3.33';`

Answer (score 1):

When you create an environment with Glassfish + MySQL, it means, that Glassfish and MySQL are separate servers with different IP.
In your case:

192.168.3.32 - MySQL server's IP. (database server)
192.168.3.33 - GlassFish server's IP. (application server)

As we see, from your output, you are trying to connect from application server to application server. This is wrong, because 192.168.3.33 - is an IP of glassfish, not MySQL.
For proper connection, you should to use an IP 192.168.3.32 as IP of your DB.

More details about Java server connection to MySQL you cand find at our [documentation page](https://docs.jelastic.com/connection-to-mysql).